# How to get sun streaks /lens flare effect in compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes, emission

I am making a space scene in blender [image]

The sphere with that emission material is supposed to be the sun .I remember doing somthing with the Index OB pass so I have it enabled.I wan't to get sun streaks like this:[image]

How do I get this effect using the compositor?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4KLfzmey58 maybe try out this addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution to this problem I could of course use the Flares Wizard addon as @Jonas said yet the question was how it can be done with the compositor. This is how it can be done:

1. Add in a sphere which should be the sun
2. Give it an emission material with a strength of 10
3. Navigate to the object properties panel and in the relations ->Change the pass index of the sphere to 1
4. Navigate to View layer properties and in the passes-> enable object index (IndexOB)
5. Hit Render
6. Open up the compositor and use the node setup as shown:
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Then you will get this:
[image]

PS:If your sphere is too big you will need to tweak the node setup.Likewise adding in a blur node in between can smoothen out that sharp streaks...
This is the rendered result:
[image]

If you want just sun glare you can you this node setup:
[image](*Add node near render layers node is not necessary*)

Which will get you this effect :
[image]

**When adding the sun beams node make sure to place the cross in the middle of the sun**